# Cannot update the view or function 'cte' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, having

I want to delete using Having by .

So i try to execute the following statement :

```
;WITH cte As
(
 select  emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year] 
from empmission
group by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
having count(*) >2
)

DELETE 
FROM    cte
```

but i get the following exception :

> Cannot update the view or function 'cte' because it contains
>   aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT
>   operator.

Comment: I want to delete where `having count(*) >2`

Comment: Delete from empmission not cte where all your key values match.

Comment: @xQbert : Could you write the query please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
WITH todelete As (
      select em.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
                                order by (select null)) as cnt
      from empmission em
)

DELETE FROM todelete
WHERE cnt > 2;
```

Note that this deletes *all* rows with duplicate values.  Often, you want to keep one of the values.  If that is the case, ask another question.

Comment: `The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY`

Comment: :Thanks but it's so slow i can't run it

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare . . . The `row_number()` an take advantage of an index on `empmission(emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year])`.

Answer (score 3):

inner join back to the original table and delete it.

```
;WITH cte As
(
 select   emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year] 
 from     empmission
 group by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
 having   count(*) >2
)    
DELETE E
FROM   cte C
JOIN   empmission E   ON  C.emp_num  = E.emp_num
                      AND C.from_date = E.from_date
                      AND C.to_date   = E.to_date
                      AND C.req_ser   = E.req_ser
                      AND C.req_year  = E.req_year
```

Comment: I think you may need to key off of all columns in the select not just emp_num but I'm not certain without table structure.

Comment: how big is the table ? and what are the index in that table ?

Comment: No indexes , and i want to delete the duplicates  to add the indexes

Comment: you can still add the necessary index first for the query

Answer (score 2):

An other approach, skip the cte, do `EXISTS` instead:

```
delete from empmission e1
where exists (select 1
              from empmission e2
              where e1.emp_num = e1.emp_num
                and e1.[from_date] = e2.[from_date]
                and e1.[to_date] = e2.[to_date]
                and e1.[ req_ser] = e2.[ req_ser]
                and e1.[ req_year] = e2.[ req_year]
              group by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
              having count(*) > 2)
```